# How to make a table element always stay at the center?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a component with only a table to display.
This is my render:

```
<Grid container>
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
                <Table color="teal" inverted>
```

Problem is that the table seems to be at the left of the screen, I cannot seem to put it exactly at the center.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This might help -:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use React-Material then this is helpful for you-

```
   <Grid 
       container 
       direction="column" 
       justify="center" 
        alignItems = "center">
        <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <Table color="teal" inverted>
```